# Hibernate dialect

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to accessing data from sql server 2008.while executing the following code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
String qry="select Form_Id,SUBSTRING( 
       (SELECT ( '' + t2.Form_Layout_Txt) FROM Form_Layout_Info t2  
            WHERE t1.Form_Id = t2.Form_Id " +
            " GROUP BY Form_Layout_Txt FOR XML path('') ), 1,1000000000) 
             FROM Form_Layout_Info t1 GROUP BY  Form_Id";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(qry);
recordList = query.list();
```

My Hibernate properties is

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=abc;integratedSecurity=false;
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
hibernate.connection.username=sa
hibernate.connection.password=p123asc
```

i received the following error

```
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

How to fix the issue.

Comment: No it is not null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` in configuration for sql server.

Either provide it in hibernate.cfg.xml as :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="session-factory">
        .....
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        ....
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

or in properties file as :

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I don't know which way you are using, so posted both I know.

I found 2 solutions for your problem [here](http://devnumbertwo.com/ms-sql-server-hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9/):

1. try changing your driver to jTDS
   using the ms sql server jdbc driver provided by microsoft can cause this issue while jTDS does not give this complaint.
2. you may need to explicitly “addScalar” to your hibernate query. You might have something like this:

   sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS");
   // try changing to:
   sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
    .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
    .addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("BIRTHDATE", Hibernate.DATE)

Comment: actually i have used as hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect.Is that correct?

Comment: i have posted my configuration

Comment: I can see correct dialect in your configuration. Are you still getting error?

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, upvoted. I use the same config.

Comment: can you post the complete exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to type mapping done while returning data. And mapping for that particular data type not exists in Dialect.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=959583

Hibernate Data types -

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/StandardBasicTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

The error means hibernate doesn’t know how to map the JDBC type “NVARCHAR” to a hibernate type.

Solution 1:
Using addScalar like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
String qry="select Form_Id,SUBSTRING( 
   (SELECT ( '' + t2.Form_Layout_Txt) as formLayoutTxt FROM Form_Layout_Info t2  
        WHERE t1.Form_Id = t2.Form_Id " +
        " GROUP BY Form_Layout_Txt FOR XML path('') ), 1,1000000000) 
         FROM Form_Layout_Info t1 GROUP BY  Form_Id";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(qry).addScalar("formLayoutTxt", StringType.INSTANCE);
recordList = query.list();
```

Solution 2: Register the Hibernate Type in Dialect

```
public class MySQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

  public MySQLServerDialect() {
    super();

    // Register mappings
    registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StringType.INSTANCE.getName());
  }
}
```

For more details, check out [this](http://jkssweetlife.com/fix-hibernate-dialect-mapping-jdbc-type/).

Comment: Link at end of answer seems dead.